# Method cells of object global failed vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using the code below to reference a range in excel and put a value into them. The code works fine first time round but fails if i dot it again. I get the error message (see title). Below is my code, can anyone see any issues?

```
xlApp.Workbooks("JDE1.xlsx").Sheets("TempHours").Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 18)).Value = Batch
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question and I happen to land on this but I will still go ahead an answer it.

You need to fully qualify your cells object. Notice the DOT before `cells()`? One should always fully qualify the objects like you did for `Sheets("TempHours")`.

```
With xlApp.Workbooks("JDE1.xlsx").Sheets("TempHours")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 18), .Cells(.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 18)).Value = Batch
End With
```

Hope this helps future visitors.